# How to import Swift code into Objective-C code, when createing React Native Fabric Native Component?

Tags: swift, objective-c, typescript, react-native

I try to create Fabric Native Component following The Guide from [text](https://reactnative.dev/docs/the-new-architecture/pillars-fabric-components)

The Fabric Native Component is working like charm!

But, I want to write code with Swift and call it in existing Objective-C files. Here are files from tutorial, that I made change:

[image: Swift code]

[image: Obj-C code that I want to call Swift object into]

[image: Obj-C code that I want to call Swift object into]

Swift method is not invoking and printing text:

```
    @objc func mySwiftMethod() {
        print("This is a Swift method from MySwiftClass.swift")
    }
```

I created a RTNCenteredText-Bridging-Header.h file and added those line in it:

```
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "React/RCTViewManager.h"
#import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"
#import "React/RCTUIManager.h"
```

> This is native component, and path to it is different than sey/ios. Accordingly there is any .xcodeproj, too.

How do I make interact Swift and Obj-C code in Native component?
Is that way of creating bridging header file is correct?
Have to I create .xcodeproj in sey/RTNCenteredText? I start to think about it when I read code of react-native-track-player library.

Thank you for any answer!